# PHP large array performance

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I have a very large array in which i want to compare each element to its previous element.

Is it good practice (and better performance) if for each element i'm finished with i'll remove that element using array_pop?

Thanks.

Comment: its better to test yourself such cases

Comment: If you expect to have just one value at the end, then it sounds more like a case for array_reduce() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php and then simply unsetting the original array if you no longer need it

Comment: I think removing the scanned elements won't help you. because you must scan the list at least once which is O(n).

Comment: try v8 engine: http://www.php.net/manual/en/v8js.examples.php

Comment: @Userpassword - what's the relevance of v8 engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you and I were dealing with a non associative array I would do

```
$n = count($array);
for($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++){
    //compare $array[$i] to $array[$i - 1]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Start at one and then go up.

No need to pop.

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($arr); ++$i) {
   //some comparison of $arr[$i -1] and $arr[$i]
}
```

Comment: why every loop do count() ???

Comment: @Userpassword  if you really want to cache the number of elements in the array you can do that too

Comment: PHP Mythbusters: Count inside for loop is slow   ------ http://www.codeforest.net/php-mythbusters-count-inside-for-loop-is-slow